# Changing default route in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

as i'm new to Razor Pages concept in ASP.NET Core, i want to apply a general URL to pass the culture parameter to the route

i have done that using MVC but i would like also to apply it with Razor pages 
here is what i have done in MVC and its working as needed

```
  routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{culture}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

i have applied it with specific Page and its working too

```
   options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/RealEstate/Index", "{culture}/RealEstate");
```

but when i want to apply for all pages it doesn't work and i don't know what should be passed as a PageName

```
 options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("*", "{culture}/{*url}");
```

also i want to exclude the admin folder from this convention to be siteName.com/admin instead of en-US/Admin also i need to set a default culture in the URL when the user opens the site for first time, like for example to be siteName.com and loads default culture, or even loads siteName.com/en-US by Default

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can apply a route model convention to a folder using [`AddFolderRouteModelConvention`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.applicationmodels.pageconventioncollection.addfolderroutemodelconvention?view=aspnetcore-2.1). The docs have an [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/razor-pages-conventions?view=aspnetcore-2.1#page-route-action-conventions) of how to do this, which I've taken and modified for your purposes:

```cs
options.Conventions.AddFolderRouteModelConvention("/", model =>
{
    foreach (var selector in model.Selectors)
    {
        selector.AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel
        {
            Order = -1,
            Template = AttributeRouteModel.CombineTemplates(
                "{culture}",
                selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template),
        };
    }
});
```

This applies a convention to all pages, given that `"/"` is set as the folder and therefore applies at the root level. Rather than adding a new selector as in the example I linked, this modifies the existing selector to prepend the `{culture}` token, which you can access in your pages by name, e.g.:

```cs
public void OnGet(string culture)
{
    // ...
}
```

Had we *added* a *new* selector, the pages would be accessible both with and without the culture, making it optional. With the approach I've shown, the `{culture}` token is required, as indicated in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the helping of Kirk Larkin

i used his answer and i added a small modification to exclude Admin from the culture routing also to set default culture for the website when no culture chosen

```
options.Conventions.AddFolderRouteModelConvention("/", model =>
                   {
                       foreach (var selector in model.Selectors)
                       {
                           if (selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template.StartsWith("Admin"))
                           {
                               selector.AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel
                               {
                                   Order = -1,
                                   Template =
                                       selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template,
                               };
                           }
                           else
                           {
                               selector.AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel
                               {
                                   Order = -1,
                                   Template = AttributeRouteModel.CombineTemplates(
                                       "{culture=en-US}",
                                       selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template),
                               };
                           }

                       }
                   });
```

Comment: how did you fix the default language? This line Template = AttributeRouteModel.CombineTemplates(
                                       "{culture=en-US}" isn't working for me.