# How do i change startup url path of Razor Page Application so it can load a specific .cshtml

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I want to load my application at `http://localhost:52856/CRUD/Products/List` so then i can start working on the `List.cshtml` file instead of loading `Index.cshtml` at `http://localhost:52856` . 
Look i know i can just put a button at the index file so then it can redirect to path or use the *navbar*, but personally i don't want to do that every single time.Just load the application at the `file.cshtml` i want. But How can i do it?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50698799/changing-default-route-in-asp-net-core-razor-pages

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change starting page, using Razor Pages in .NET Core 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46117717/how-to-change-starting-page-using-razor-pages-in-net-core-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't like my comment you could do the following in Index.cshtml.cs

```
public IActionResult OnGet()
{
    return new RedirectToPageResult("/CRUD/Product/List");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**1. Include MVC as a service into our app.**
we can optionally use another method called `AddRazorPagesOptions()` like so:

```
services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
        {
            options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Customer/Index", "");
        });
```

Within that `AddRazorPagesOptions()` method, we can set things like route conventions and the root directory for pages. It turns out that, to set a default route for a page.

**2. remove or rename Pages/Index.cshtml**